# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, macos

I am trying to set up a Java IDE on my Mac running El Capitan, however the installer that I have found requires me to install a separate IDE for C/C++ and Java (Eclipse Neon). What options does eclipse have that would me to have one IDE for multiple languages?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Eclipse is a platform. Install either. Then run it. Click "Help > Install New Software ..." then in the "Work with" drop down select "Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/", then expand "Programming Languages" and select "C/C++" or "Java" as desired.

[image: Programming Languages]

And you can switch *modes* with "Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other"

[image: Open Perspective]

Comment: @ShashwatKumar If you click on each option they will tell you (in the details) what each option does, the thing is they do many different things. Because it depends on what kind of C++ you want to do. Are you targeting console applications, shared libraries, embedded systems, cross-platform, native, windowing and/or threading code? Which compiler do you have? Etc. Etc.

Answer (score 10):

Just try to open a `*.cpp` file in your IDE, Eclipse will then prompt for possible plugins to install. This include the `Eclipse C/C++ IDE` plugins, that is the "official" one from Eclipse community.

Comment: Easiest option.