# Eclipse installation issue

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

It is possible to install Eclipse for Java and C++ in the same time for same Pc? Thanks ☺️
I’m Java Developer but also I need eclipse even for C++ projects.
It is that possible ?

Comment: It's been a while since I last used eclipse, but I'm pretty sure you can install both as extensions to the base IDE.

Comment: Assuming [the normal](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/7/7d/OomphSimpleInstaller2.png) installer, you should be able to download all the eclipse types you need. You may need to make sure they get installed in to separate folders, but the default folder should be fine. (Though I haven't tested this myself)

Comment: Yes, You can see the process by visiting this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283629/eclipse-ide-for-c-c-and-java#:~:text=Eclipse%20is%20a%20platform.,or%20%22Java%22%20as%20desired.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options:

- install Eclipse/Java and Eclipse/C++ in different folders on the same computer
- Install either Eclipse/Java or Eclipse/C++, then further install the plugins for the missing language

The first one is trivial as it is just two downloads.
For the second, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283723/4222206